# Creating smooth video transitions in unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, video, transition

I'm currently trying to make a mobile game (android) in which the player movement around a scene consists of pre-rendered video clips that are triggered when a certain direction is selected by the user. This approach is very much inspired by certain classic games that made use of pre-rendered backgrounds and video clips - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fsH4_8NyGco&t=717s?

I have created a script to set the video player frame to the relevant point in a video clip in order to play these transitions when required, however the issue that I am facing is that once loaded onto an android device, there is a very much noticeable delay between the video frame being chosen and the video playing.

It seems to me as if it takes the unity video player a certain amount of time to skip to a certain point in the video, which causes this delay between the command and the output. I have tried to reduce this time by creating individual clips, encoding in a range of different codecs and making sure to use unity's 'Prepare' function at the start of the scene, however I'm still yet to be able create the smooth transition that I am after.

Might anyone have any advice that they could kindly offer? I have searched all over and found a number of similar posts on forums, but have yet to find any real solution to this issue.

Comment: Really hacky solution, whatever you are using to render the video (i'm assuming it's something along the lines of an object in unity that you are texturing with the video), have multiple of them existing in your world ready to play at the times you want to play them and move them into the veiw when they are to be played, as opposed to having one object you play video off and skipping around in the clip. This would allow multiple streams of the video to exist in various states and performed quite well when i used it

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jake. I'm currently using a single render texture, to which the video player is then linked. I will have a go using your method and see if I'm able to speed things up. Thank you!